# Populate cells on one sheet from data on another based on a user-defined variable that dictates the range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm trying to build an inspection report template for solar installations and am somewhat new to complex Excel usage (and brand new to VBA), but very comfortable with programming and learning fast!

Ideally, the user would input the number of inverters at the installation (Currently up to 12) and the template would populate the appropriate number of premade checklists with a drop-down good/bad for each checklist item, 1 for each inverter numbered in consecutive order (Inverter #1, Inverter #2, etc.).

In the workbook, I have a main sheet titled "Report," a second sheet titled "Fill Data," and a third sheet titled "Buttons&Lists."

On "Report", cell A7 is "Total Number of Inverters Onsite" with the input going in cell D7 and the cell population starting in A9.

On "Fill Data," there is a data range in A4:X15 that is the 12 checklists (A4:B15 is Inverter #1, C4:D15 is Inverter #2, etc). In this range, the second column of each checklist has drop-down lists for each item giving "null/good/bad" options from a list at 'Buttons&Lists'!$A$2:$A$4.

[image: Partial 'Fill Data' Screen shot]

I have tried an extremely long IF formula: =IF(D7=1,'Fill Data'!A4:B15,IF(D7=2,'Fill Data'!A4:D15,IF(D7=3,'Fill Data'!A4:F15,IF(D7=4,'Fill Data'!A4:H15,IF(D7=5,'Fill Data'!A4:J15,IF(D7=6,'Fill Data'!A4:L15,IF(D7=7,'Fill Data'!A4:N15,IF(D7=8,'Fill Data'!A4:P15,IF(D7=9,'Fill Data'!A4:R15,IF(D=10,'Fill Data'!A4:T15,IF(D7=11,'Fill Data'!A4:V15,'Fill Data'!A4:X15)))))))))))

This partly does the job, except the functionality of the "null/good/bad" drop-down lists don't come through (just the current selection) and it breaks if the user inputs 12. Currently, the number of inverters stops at 12, though I would love to build an open-ended template that could populate as many checklists as needed.

[image: 'Report' Screenshot with input 12]

[image: 'Report' Screenshot with input 3]

I suspect that a VBA script might be the best way to accomplish this, but have no idea how to make it look at D7 and adjust the copy and paste accordingly, or copy 1 checklist and change the inverter number as it executes the appropriate number of multiple pastes.

There also may be a simpler way somewhere between the IF function and VBA that I know nothing about. I'm not looking for a completed script or formula, just guidance on how I might develop it.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of no replies on Super User, I posed the same question on Microsoft. Probably should have gone there first. I share this for the next person who might have this question.

[The VBA script that solves my problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-get-an-excel-workbook-to-populate-cells/5ec7a54b-ee9f-4930-9051-389f2e8d0474)

All I got here was some views, some editing that felt overly critical and not particularly helpful, a down-voted question, and an "answer" that was plausible but not at all the direction I want to go with the project. Not a very good first experience.

Comment: Please replicate the script here